# Route VPN Through Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, vpn

I'm on a network which requires out-going traffic to pass through an http proxy.

I would like to connect to my remote VPN through the proxy, but am not sure how to do this. Any thoughts?

I am running Lubuntu with the "network-manager-vpnc" installed.

Comment: Not all VPNs can go over a web proxy. I'm not familiar with Cisco VPN, I think it supports several transport mechanisms. How is your VPN set up? Please post the complete configuration apart from the IP address and authentication.

Comment: man openvpn # and look at proxy settings

Answer (score 1):

Read this [how-to](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http).

You can use openvpn with http, socks4 or socks5 proxy.

This is similarly to default launching, but specify proxy server, e.g.:

```
# openvpn --config config.file --http-proxy 127.0.0.1 3128
```

However, http proxy doesn't support UDP, probably you can do this only with TCP vpn.

But you can read about --socks-proxy, socks5 support UDP, may be this will be your choice.